# How to get the number of spanCount(number of columns)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am currently working on a refactoring task which requires replacing ListView(GridView) by RecyclerView.

In a part of the job, it requires to get the span count.
As the former code has a method to get the number of columns of GridView like this:

```
public int getNumColumns()
```

Then I am wondering that if there is a same method in RecyclerView?

Your answers are highly appreciated.

Sincerely,
Jack

I tried something like:

```
mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().getColumnCountForAccessibility()
```

But apparently, this is only for the sake of horizontal scrolling.

```
public int getNumColumns()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using,

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = (GridLayoutManager)mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
int spanCount = layoutManager.getSpanCount()
```